# body не растягивается на весь экран

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Все учусь верстать)) Раньше верстала макеты с помощью view port и вроде все нормально получалось, но надо разбираться и с пикселями, и решила сверстать макет в пикселях. Пока как-то все не очень комфортно)) 
Проблема в том что при уменьшении ширины экрана мой блок категорически отказывается растягиваться на всю ширину. Посмотрите пожалуйста код, скорее всего где-то опечатка, но я ее в упор не вижу)) И скорее всего она во второй секции, так как если ее закомментировать, то все вреде нормально)) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@charset utf-8;
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,
abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,
strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,
legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{background: none repeat scroll 0
0 transparent; border: 0 none; font-size: 100%; outline: 0 none; vertical-align: 
baseline;margin: 0;padding: 0;}table{border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;}
address,article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,
section,summary{display: block;}

* {
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

a, a:hover, button, button:hover, .anime {
 -moz-transition:all 200ms linear;
 -ms-transition:all 200ms linear;
 -o-transition:all 200ms linear;
 -webkit-transition:all 200ms linear;
 transition:all 200ms linear;
 cursor: pointer;
}

body {
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.wrap {
 width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background-color:#fff;
 padding-bottom: 90px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
 width: 631px;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: 'Roboto_regular';
 color: #989696;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 line-height: 17px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

nav li {
 list-style: none;
}

nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #989696;
}

nav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

nav a:hover {
 color: #000;
}

.logo {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 55px;
 height: 55px;
}

.logo img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.active {
 color: #000;
}

.content_header {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center;
 margin-top: 298px;

}

.content_header h1 {
 font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt';
 font-size: 44px;
 line-height: 17px
 color: #1d1e1f;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: normal;

}

.content_header p {
 font-family: 'Merriweather_Light_Italic';
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 17px;
 color: #898888;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 43px;
}

.btn {
 color: #000;
 font-family: 'Montserra_regular';
 font-size: 13px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 23px 51px;
}

.btn:hover {
 background-color: #000;
 color:#fff;
}

.button_down {
 margin-top: 275px;
}

.circle {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin-top: 12px;
}

.circle:nth-child(1) {
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 -webkit-animation: load_one 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 -webkit-animation: load_two 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
 background-color: #d0d0d0;
 -webkit-animation: load_three 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}


@-webkit-keyframes load_one {
 
 25% {opacity: 1}
 50% {opacity: 0}
}

@-webkit-keyframes load_two {
 0% {opacity: 0}
 50% {opacity: 1}
 75% {opacity: 0}
 
}

@-webkit-keyframes load_three {
 0% {opacity: 0}
 75% {opacity: 1}
 100% {opacity: 0}
}

#about {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
 background-image: url(../img/bg_about.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: bottom;
}


.title_about_right {
 font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTPro_Roman';
 font-size: 48px;
 line-height: 26px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: right;
}

.title_about_left {
 font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTPro_Roman';
 font-size: 48px;
 line-height: 26px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: left;
}

.content_about p{
 margin-top: 29px;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat_Light';
 line-height: 22px;
 color: #b7b7b7;
 text-align: left;
}

.container_about {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 150px;
 padding-bottom: 460px;
}

.container_about:before {
 content:'';
  display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:calc(50% - 5px);
 height:100%;
 border-left:5px solid #fff;
}


.content_about {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.content_about:nth-child(2n){
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.content_about:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:#1d1d1d;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  
  right: -90px;
}

.content_about:nth-child(2n):before{
  right:auto;
  left:-94px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>B&M</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="wrap">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
     <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
     </div>
     <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

   <div class="content_header">
    <h1>We build it with passion</h1> 
    <p>Just to be clear, we do this for fun not for you, just kidding.</p>
    <button class="btn">read more</button>

    <div class="button_down">
     <div class="circle"></div>
     <div class="circle"></div>
     <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>

 <section id="about">
  <div class="wrap container_about">
   <div  class="content_about">
    <div class="title_about_right">
     2011
    </div>

    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiselit. Vivamus varius nec diam vitae hendrerit bigus mit.
    </p>
   </div>

   <div class="content_about">
    <div class="title_about_left">
     2012
    </div>

    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiselit. Vivamus varius nec diam vitae hendrerit bigus mit.
     Begitus vit urna nulla.
    </p>
   </div>

   <div class="content_about">
    <div class="title_about_right">
     2013
    </div>

    <p>
     Sed at auctor sem, nec tincidunt elit. Pellentesque enim turpis, porttitor ac orci in, ultrices efficitur nisl. Ut odio libero, sodales a tellus eleifend, suscipit dapibus mi.
    </p>
   </div>


   <div class="content_about">
    <div class="title_about_left">
     2014
    </div>

    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiselit. Vivamus varius nec diam vitae hendrerit bigus mit.
     Begitus vit urna nulla.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Учтите, эта функция (посмотреть, как будет выглядеть сайт в других раршерешниях) - иногда работает некорректно.

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev какая функция?)

Answer (score 1):

Так media screen используй

```
@media (max-width 767px){
  .container{
      width: 100%;
   } 
}
```

Comment: не работает))))

Comment: Зачем тут media? И класс тоже не тот.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать ваш код без сторонних стилей, то все выглядит нормально.
Вы уверены что не стоит задавать `body{ width: 100%}`, а так же я не совсем понимаю, как в вас `<div class="wrap"></div>` должен выравниваться по центру. Сам DIV у вас стоит скраю, а не `body`

Comment: Я указывала body{ width: 100%}, но ничего не изменилось. Ну задумка в том, что блок контейнера равен всей ширине экрана, а блок div.wrap выравнивает контент по центру (margin: 0 auto;) родительского блока.

Comment: Я вижу, поставив ваш код себе, что все в нем нормально, не совсем понимаю пока, зачем вам в пикселях указывать ширину, но у меня все отображает нормально.

Comment: НА весь экран у меня тоже все нормально отображается, а при уменьшение возникает такая вот проблема. А в чем разве нужно указывать ширину?

Comment: Для responsive верстки ширину всегда лучше указывать в `%`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .wrap {
>     width: 1170px;
>     margin: 0 auto;
> }
> ```

Ну а с чего ему растягиваться-то? Добавь

```
max-width: 100%;
```

Comment: Если задать max-width: 100%; то оно все вроде бы и растягивается, но отступы для текста и для кругов заданы в пикселях, и они теперь играют как гармошка. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: и мой класc wrap теряет смысл, так как он не задает рамки контенту, контент растягивается на всю ширину